# JavaFX выдает ошибку при вызове изображения

Tags: java, javafx

Помогите пожалуйста. Никак не могу понять(Начинающий "джавист"). JavaFX постоянно пишет вот эту ошибку:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\javafx-sdk\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=8213:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\java\newapplication\out\production\newapplication;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\src.zip;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\javafx-sdk\lib\javafx.graphics.jar ImageDemo
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:617)
    at ImageDemo.start(ImageDemo.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:664)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:553)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:500)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1104)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application ImageDemo

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вот это код программы:

```
//работа с изображением
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;


public class ImageDemo extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //запуск приложения
        launch(args);
    }

    //переопр метод start
    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        myStage.setTitle("Display an Image.");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode,300,200);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);

        Image bob = new Image("C:\\java\\bob.jpg");
        ImageView bobIV = new ImageView(bob);

        rootNode.getChildren().add(bobIV);
        myStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте прямые слеши (`/`) вместо обратных

Comment: insolor, пробовал. И через getClass().getResourсе() пробовал. Все одно - эта ошибка ((. Отчаялся уже

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту статью: [Руководство JavaFX Image и ImageView](https://o7planning.org/ru/11127/javafx-image-and-imageview-tutorial)

Comment: insolor, Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь к image-файлу следует указать по схеме [URI file](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_URI)). Например так:

```
Image bob = new Image("file:///java//bob.jpg");
```

Comment: Прямой слеш не требует экранирования.

Comment: Можно так  -  file:///java/bob.jpg. Но оба варианта работают.

Comment: anshap, insolor - благодарю Вас от всей души. Мне это очень помогло. Почитал руководство, посмотрел на вики и все сделал. Вы супер! Спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрАнцупов, добавьте ваше решение как ответ

Comment: @insolor, зачем? :-) Я отметил ответом запись Anshap. Я бы и Вашу с удовольствием отметил ответом, но там нет галочки для этого. :-/

Comment: @АлександрАнцупов, если ваше решение такое же как у anshap, тогда ок. Если отличается - то лучше отдельным ответом. Я только дал ссылку на руководство, это не тянет на ответ.

Comment: @insolor, я немного сократил: ```ImageView bobIV = new ImageView("file:///java/bob.jpg");``` Вставив сразу через класс ImageView. Поэтому мой ответ, считай, ничем не отличается от предложенного. А статья, которую Вы предложили - отличная документация, которая помогла. Я по Шилдту учу Java, поэтому немного сложно.

Comment: @insolor, прошу извинить, что поздно заметил ваш комментарий, проверял своё решение под IDEA. По сути, ваш ответ в комментарии был достаточным. Но я заметил его, уже позже, введя свой вариант ответа.